# Unwanted repeating html result from PHP

Tags: php

I don't know what is wrong with this code, it is a bug or I made a mistake somewhere; xDebug show nothing.

#### Class script

```
class theme {
    function theme() {
        //show header (meta, style, htmldoctype, script, and title) 
        $this->htmlheader();

        //show main content
        //show footer
    }


    function htmlheader() {
        require "localsettings.php";
        echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n";

        echo "<title>$site_name - $page_title</title>\n";
        echo "</head>\n";
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
require "theme.class.php";
$html = new theme();
//display result
$html->theme();
```

#### Output (incorrectly repeated)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>site title - </title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>site title - </title>
</head>
```

Comment: It says `//display result` and then your displaying the result again? with `$html->theme();` ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any special reason you are not using PHP 5? PHP 4 has been discontinued since 2007-12-31.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you name the function the same as the class, it is a "constructor", and gets called when the class is instantiated.  Thus, your function `theme()` is called both here:

```
$html = new theme();
```

and here:

```
$html->theme();
```

Remove the latter, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Note that in PHP5 you could use `__construct` for the constructor (more explicit=better imo).

Comment: @ChristopheD It shouldn't be a big surprise though; it's pretty common in other languages for the class name to represent a constructor